# Insert set of fields/document properties automatically

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, macros, templates

I'm fairly new to Word 2007.  (Coming more from a Linux/text editor background.)  Each time I create a document within Word 2007, I add a set of details to the start of the document.

It's the same set of details each time -- Author, Date Created, Date Last Modified, and Status, formatted in the same way each time.

I include these bits of information either by inserting Fields (`Insert -> Quick Parts -> Insert Field`) or Document Properties (`Insert -> Quick Parts -> Document Properties -> ...`).

I'm just wondering how I would go about setting up a macro or a template or something along those lines to insert this information automatically, either by a keypress in an existing document, or each time I start a new document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new document with all this information filled in then do "Save as > Word Template".

This will create a new template(!) which you can then use as the basis for all your subsequent documents.